# Add an UIButton to ViewController from custom class

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have one class named "Menu" creating UIButton:

.h file:

```
@interface Menu : NSObject

@property (strong) Forme *forme;
@property (strong) NSString *imageButtonName;
@property (strong) UIButton *button;

- (id) initWithClef:(int)clef hauteur:(int)hauteur largeur:(int)largeur posY:(int)posY posX:(int)posX alpha:(float)alpha imageButtonName:(NSString*)imageButtonName button:(UIButton*)button;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "Menu.h"

@implementation Menu

@synthesize forme = _forme;
@synthesize button = _button;
@synthesize imageButtonName = _imageButtonName;

- (id) initWithClef:(int)clef hauteur:(int)hauteur largeur:(int)largeur posY:(int)posY posX:(int)posX alpha:(float)alpha imageButtonName:(NSString *)imageButtonName button:(UIButton *)button
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
        {
            NSLog (@"test2");
            self.forme =[[Forme alloc]initWithClef:clef hauteur:hauteur largeur:largeur posY:posY posX:posX alpha:alpha];
            self.button = button;
            [button setFrame:CGRectMake(largeur, hauteur, posX, posY)];
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageButtonName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    return self;
}
```

I want to automatically display created Buttons to the ViewController view. Is someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and add onView parameter to your initClef....

```
- (id) initWithClef:(int)clef hauteur:(int)hauteur largeur:(int)largeur posY:(int)posY posX:(int)posX alpha:(float)alpha imageButtonName:(NSString *)imageButtonName button:(UIButton *)button onView:(UIView *)view
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSLog (@"test2");
 //       self.forme =[[Forme alloc]initWithClef:clef hauteur:hauteur largeur:largeur posY:posY posX:posX alpha:alpha];
        self.button = button;
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(largeur, hauteur, posX, posY)];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageButtonName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [view addSubview:button];

    }
    return self;
}
```

call it in viewController

```
 Menu * menu2=[[Menu alloc] initWithClef:1 hauteur:30 largeur:30 posY:30 posX:30 alpha:1 imageButtonName:@"arti.png" button:b onView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thank you! it works.. But now I want to call it from a third class. So onView can't be "self.view". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

*I think you should read some manuals and tutorials*

Just add this button to viewcontroller's view in the init method:

```
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageButtonName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. I have olso tried : UIViewController *newview = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
            [newview.view addSubview:self.button];

Comment: In my viewDidLoad methode : Menu *play = [[Menu alloc]initWithClef:1 hauteur:100 largeur:300 posY:100 posX:50 alpha:1 imageButtonName:@"play.png" button:[[UIButton alloc]init]]; than if i add [self.view addSubview:button]; in viewDidLoad it works. But I really want to automatically display my buttons in the init methode. thanks

Comment: Replace than [[UIButton alloc]init]]; to [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];

Comment: Yes because I can display my button if I call [self.view addSubview:button] in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I think that simply adding a button to the view should do the trick,
call:

```
[self.view addSubview:button]
```

After the initialization of your button you still need to 'add' the button to the view with addSubview or else your button wont be drawn on the screen.

Comment: check your arguments in your init. Are those valid widths and heights?

Comment: Yes: Menu *play = [[Menu alloc]initWithClef:1 hauteur:100 largeur:300 posY:100 posX:50 alpha:1 imageButtonName:@"play.png" button:[[UIButton alloc]init]];